# Linking 2 cells in excel, them mapping matching cells into 1 row

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am looking to map 2 worksheets together via a like field, then concatenate  values into one cell.

For example

Sheet 1

```
ColumnA   ColumnB
hello     response1
hello     response2
hello     response3
hello     response4
goodbye   no stay1
goodbye   no stay2
goodbye   no stay3
goodbye   no stay4
goodbye   no stay5
```

sheet

```
ColumnA    ColumnB
hello      (from sheet1) response1, repsonse2 response3, response4, 
goodbye    (from sheet1) no stay1, no stay2, no stay2, no stay4, no stay5
```

can this even be done?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple link you can use this

in sheet 2 A1

=sheet1!a1
This will link cell A1 in sheet 1 with A1 in sheet 2

What ever you type in sheet 1 A1 will appear in sheet 2 A1

For batter understanding please upload a snapshot of your file.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll want VBA (I'm sure formulas could do it, but they'd be array formulas and likely pretty convoluted).

Add this to a workbook module in the workbook with your data:

```
Function MYVLOOKUP(lookupval, lookuprange As Range, indexcol As Long)
'http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/280705-vlookup-return-multiple-values-one-cell-concatenate.html
Dim r As Range
Dim result As String
result = ""
For Each r In lookuprange
    If r = lookupval Then
        result = result & " " & r.Offset(0, indexcol - 1)
    End If
Next r
MYVLOOKUP = result
End Function
```

Then, if your table is A1:B10, you'd do `=myvlookup("hello",$A$1:$B$10,2)`.  You could of course replace `"hello"` with a cell reference.

[image]